# PySpark: Not able to read hive orc table using spark.sql

Tags: python, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql, orc

Used spark to write df to hdfs:

```py
df.write.partitionBy("date").mode("append").format("ORC").save("/tmp/table1")
```

Created Hive External Table on top of this (default.table1)

I am able to read this table using beeline.

```sql
select * from default.table1; --> works fine
```

I am able to read this folder using spark

```py
spark.read.orc("/tmp/table1").show()  # --> works fine
```

However, when I use spark to read this hive table, i am getting error:

```py
spark.sql("select * from default.table1").show() # --> error
```

When i take a count of this table, it works fine also:

```py
spark.sql("select count(*) from default.table1").show() # --> works fine
```

Also, when I write spark df as csv to hdfs, i have no issues in reading it as spark.sql (hive)

Following is the error message:

> "Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling 0192.showString."

Comment: Why do you write a file and create an external table on top of it ? why don't you just create the table directly ? `df.write.saveAsTable("default.table1", mode="append", format="orc", partitionBy="date", path="/tmp/table1")`

Comment: works fine when i do this. Any reason why it is not working when i write first and then create table on top of it?

Comment: Maybe a problem between spark and the Hive Metastore. There may be some clues in the full log of the error message. `An error occurred` is totally abstract and useless ...

Comment: Thanks @Steven. I managed to fix the issue. The problem was with my create table statement. I missed out this line: "WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ....."

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix the issue by fixing the hive ddl.

Must include the line

"WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ..." to make sure hiveContext is able to read the data in spark